# How to remove from file specific content from another file?

Tags: shell, sed, command

I have a file foo.txt:

$cat foo.txt

```
<ul>
<li>
<p>something</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>something else</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

And a bar.txt:

$cat bar.txt

```
<li>
<p>something</p>
</li>
```

And I want the desired output:

```
<ul>
<li>
<p>something else</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried:

```
$sed '{/r bar.txt/} d' foo.txt
```

But it didn't work, and I cannot do:

```
$sed '/<li>/,/</li>/ d' foo.txt
```

because there are other elements.

Comment: In sed the r command reads a file into the output stream, not as part of the script. You load a script with `sed -f script ...`, but that won't work because bar.txt isn't a valid sed script. You would need an intermediate step to turn bar.txt into valid sed commands.

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner works for your example:

```
 awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/\n/,"\x99")}NR==FNR{t=$0;next}{gsub(t,"");gsub(/\x99/,"\n");print}' bar foo
```

not exactly the same output (empty line), but you got the idea. see the short explanation below the example.

see the example below:

```
kent$  head foo bar
==> foo <==
<ul>
<li>
<p>something</p>
</li>
<li>
<p>something else</p>
</li>
</ul>

==> bar <==
<li>
<p>something</p>
</li>

kent$  awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/\n/,"\x99")}NR==FNR{t=$0;next}{gsub(t,"");gsub(/\x99/,"\n");print}' bar foo
<ul>

<li>
<p>something else</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

**Add short explanation**

The basic idea is, replace linebreak with invisible char (in example I used `\x99`), then we have two single line strings. we can do the match and replacement. after we processed the strings, replace all `\x99` back to linebreak to get the original format. This idea works for sed too, but a bit complicated, you have to make a label and play with pattern/hold spaces...

In the example I just used `RS=""` (I am a bit lazy). you could use `sprintf` function to build the one-line string, it would be more generic, since both of your real files could have empty lines. (your example doesn't however)

The point is the invisible char replacement part.

Good luck!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. There are many newlines and spaces between the tags (regular HTML) and although i had replaced \n with \n+ - it didn't help...

Comment: `\n+` is wrong.  spaces and multi `\n` are not problem. if you have empty lines, it could be problem. I mentioned in my answer. You could use sprintf function from awk to solve the empty lines problem. my current codes worked for your example here.

Answer (score 1):

sed is an excellent tool for simple subsitutions on a single line, for anything else use awk. Here is a GNU awk solution:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= 'NR==FNR{re=$0;next} {sub(re,"")} 1' bar.txt foo.txt
<ul>
<li>
<p>something else</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

If "bar.txt" can contain RE metacharacters and you find those causing undesirable matches in the sub() (unlikely when matching large amounts of text) then you need to switch to an index()+substr()s solution to work with strings instead of REs, e.g.:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '
   NR==FNR { str=$0; rlength=length(str); next }
   rstart = index($0,str) { $0 = substr($0,1,rstart-1) substr($0,rstart+rlength) }
   1' bar.txt foo.txt
<ul>
<li>
<p>something else</p>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: None of them work :(
Maybe the "bar.txt" is too complex?: `<li>
    <div style="slidecontent">
        <div class="slideleft">
            <a href="http://url/"><img src="img/img.jpg" border="0"/></a>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <div class="tx">
            <h2>headline</h2>
            <p><strong>something<br/> something</strong><br/><br/>  something<br>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
` (it spreads across multiple lines)

Comment: "None of them work" will not help us solve the problem as it doesn't tell us what the problem is. Posting a bunch of HTML in a comment will not help either. The script I posted definitely WILL work if your input file looks like the sample input you posted in your question. It your real input doesn't look like your sample input then of course the script won't work. Try running `cat -v` on your input file to see if there are control-Ms at the end of your lines, as would happen if you created the input file on Windows.

Comment: @user2275835 - the content of "to_remove" does not match the content of "index.html"? The latter has a "<br>" line on it's own between the line that starts with "<p>" and the "</div>" and the text at the end of the <p> line is totally different between the 2. I'll post the 2 and highlight the differences.

Comment: Oh my gosh.... so much time wasted because of wrong text selection... Thank you so much Ed!
<is_going_to_hang_himself_on_ethernet_cable>

Comment: @user2275835 don't forget to click the check mark next to the answer if you've got one you're happy with so other posters don't waste their time coming up with different answers.